# How can I draw individual pixels in Java without using graphics classes?

Tags: java, user-interface

I don't want to use the graphics/drawing libraries. The only solution I can think of is creating thousands of 1x1 jButtons (which would obviously be impractical). Is there a better solution?

Comment: You can write your own JNI routine?

Comment: "thousands of 1x1 jButtons" brrrrr...

Comment: How is using JButton not using graphic libraries?

Answer (score 2):

The only way to draw "without using graphics functions" is populate a raw Raster with the byte values appropriate to the color map for the actual image. Then you can use a graphics primitive to render the resulting image in to a window.

Take a look BufferedImage, and work your way back from there.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this by creating a own component by extending for example JPanel and overriding the paintComponent method.

Why don't you want to use the graphics functions provided by Java?

Comment: Because it's for a school project. I'm the only one who knows how to use GUI, I'll feel like I'm cheating if I use built-in functions.

Answer (score 0):

How do you expect displaying the picture onto the screen without using a graphics library? Are you going to write a native method to display pixels onto the computer screen?